# Access intranet from my home PC

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, networking

I have a workstation that serves as my network's testing server for my web projects. This is where I keep all my updated webpages. I want to be able to monitor what changes have been made by my developers from my home PC located outside that said network. It this possible. (It has no public IP address)

Comment: What source control system do you use for your test server?  They can usually email notifications of commits.

Comment: i just want to be able to access my office network from my home as if i am in the office

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to setup a VPN between your home PC and whatever network your workstation is on. Once you've don't that you can connect to it using it's internal IP. If you are running a windows server network it's fairly straight forward to configure (a quick google search) otherwise checkout OpenVPN for linux variants.

Comment: wouldn't it be a separate network between my office station and my home pc? would i be able to view our intranet web apps from it?

Comment: If you were to connect to your office network via a VPN as I suggest it could be configured so that it appears to your home pc as if it were at the office. As such it would be able to access any features an office pc could.